# SVG Showing black color in flutter. Used flutter_svg dependency

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to render the SVG in the application using `flutter_svg: ^0.17.3+1` dependency. It renders the SVG but it is in black color. the same thing happens for all the SVG's.

In the SVG code `data-name="Layer 1"` showing error attribute data-name is not allowed here.
I search for the answer but I'm unable to find the perfect answer to this. please kindly help me to solve the issue.

```
  //flutter code

Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg_arrow.svg"),
        ),
      ),
```

///SVG image code

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 255.32 253.28">
    <defs>
        <style>.cls-1{fill:#fff;}.cls-2{fill:#a64ac9;}</style>
    </defs>
    <title>icons</title>
    <circle class="cls-1" cx="127.2" cy="125.99" r="123.03" />
    <path class="cls-2"
        d="M151.85,49.8,84.77,109.23l-9.56,8.46c-3.18,2.82-2.92,8.36,0,11.21L140.81,193l9.42,9.2c7.3,7.13,18.51-4.07,11.2-11.21l-65.6-64.09-9.41-9.2V128.9L153.5,69.47,163.06,61c7.65-6.77-3.59-18-11.21-11.2Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I removed id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1". still it renders only black color.

Comment: Thanks, It works. I referred your code and Now I'm able to do changes in my other SVG's also.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some user. As per his code. directly add the style tag fill values in path and shape.
This also work for other SVG's.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 255.32 253.28">
    <circle cx="127.2" cy="125.99" r="123.03" fill="#fff" />
    <path
        d="M151.85,49.8,84.77,109.23l-9.56,8.46c-3.18,2.82-2.92,8.36,0,11.21L140.81,193l9.42,9.2c7.3,7.13,18.51-4.07,11.2-11.21l-65.6-64.09-9.41-9.2V128.9L153.5,69.47,163.06,61c7.65-6.77-3.59-18-11.21-11.2Z"
        fill="#a64ac9" />
</svg>
```